# How to sum,multiply and divide in 1 Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

This has been bugging me for some time

table : stock

```
|   customerID   | Item  |  Quantity  |  Price  |
|     cus1       |  A    |     3      |    4    |
|     cus1       |  B    |     2      |    3    |
|     cus1       |  C    |     3      |    3    |
|     cus2       |  A    |     3      |    3.50 |
|     cus2       |  C    |     3      |    2    |
|     cus3       |  D    |     6      |    4    |
```

how to make my mysql query generate view like this below

view : stock_v

```
| cusID  | Item |Quan |Price |Tot_Qua | Tot_pri | sumtot_pri/tot_qua|
|  cus1  |  A   |  3  | 4    |   8    | 12      | 3.375             | 
|  cus1  |  B   |  2  | 3    |   8    | 6       | 3.375             | 
|  cus1  |  C   |  3  | 3    |   8    | 9       | 3.375             |
|  cus2  |  A   |  3  | 3.50 |   6    | 10.05   | 2.675             |
|  cus2  |  C   |  3  | 2    |   6    | 6       | 2.675             | 
|  cus3  |  D   |  6  | 4    |   6    | 24      | 4.00              |
```

Example for cus1.
Cus1 have 3 item which is A,B and C.
so I want some formula for

```
Tot_Qua = 3+2+3 = 8
Tot_pri = price x quan
```

and Tot_pri must sum for this cus1 record,

```
sumtot_pri = (quan x price) + (quan x price) + (quan x price)
sumtot_pri = (12) + (6) + (9)
```

because cus1 have 3 item, and last one

```
sumtot_pri / Tot_qua = 27 / 8 = 3.375
```

Need group by I think because I want to see their item. I don't care if column `tot_qua` and column `sumtot_pri/tot_qua` will duplicate the same data for each Cus.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+ you simply use window functions:

```
select s.*,
       sum(quan) over (partition by cusid) as tot_quan,
       (quan * price) as tot_price,
       sum(quan * price) over (partition by cusid) / sum(quan) over (partition by cusid) as ratio
from stock s;
```

In earlier versions, you would use subqueries or a similar mechanism.  Probably `join` and `group by` is simplest:

```
select s.*, s2.tot_quan, (s.quan * s.price) as tot_price,
       tot_tot_price / tot_quan as ratio
from stock s join
     (select cusid, sum(quan) as tot_quan,
            sum(quan * price) as tot_tot_price
      from stock s2
      group by cusid
     ) s2
     using (cusid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  customerID, item, quantity, price,
            (select sum(quantity) from stock s2 where stock.customerID = s2.customerID ) as tot_qua,
            price * quantity as tot_pri,
            (select sum(quantity * price) / sum(quantity) from stock s2 where stock.customerID = s2.customerID) as `sumtotpri/tot_qua`
from stock
order by stock.customerID, stock.item;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the results you want. It performs all the aggregation you need in a subquery then `JOIN`s that to the main table to give the desired output:

```
SELECT s.customerID
     , Item
     , Quantity
     , Price
     , Tot_Qua
     , Quantity * Price AS Tot_pri
     , Avg_Pri
FROM stock s
JOIN (SELECT customerID
           , SUM(Quantity) AS Tot_Qua
           , SUM(Quantity * Price) / SUM(Quantity) AS Avg_Pri
      FROM stock
      GROUP BY customerID) s1
    ON s1.customerID = s.customerID
```

Output:

```
customerID  Item    Quantity    Price   Tot_Qua     Tot_pri     Avg_Pri
cus1        A       3           4       8           12          3.375
cus1        B       2           3       8           6           3.375
cus1        C       3           3       8           9           3.375
cus2        A       3           3.5     6           10.5        2.75
cus2        C       3           2       6           6           2.75
cus3        D       6           4       6           24          4
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d08ed859f3033533fa40159f55503d46)